# Convert [ UNIX (LF) UTF-8 ] to [Windows (CRLF) ANSI]

Tags: powershell, google-apps-script, google-sheets, character-encoding, google-drive-api

I have a VB program that uses a database located in a text file. This file, when opened in Notepad, tells me the format is in "**WINDOWS (CRLF) |ANSI**".

- I transferred the database into a Google Sheets, which can be easily updated by multiple users.
- I have developed a Google Apps Script to extract the data from the Google Sheets into a text file on the Drive.

**The problem is** that when I retrieve the file from the Google Sheets spreadsheet, it is in "**UNIX (LF) | UTF-8**" format and when
I designate this file as the source of the VB program, it does not
display some characters properly (*"é" ; "ô" etc.*)

I tried the bash command : `Set-Content C:\Output\file.txt -Encoding Ascii` 
But I still see the "UTF-8" when I open it with Windows Notepad.

I am looking for a way to convert a text file encoded in UTF-8
recovered from a Google Drive to a file encoded in ANSI
(Windows-1252).
I take the solution no matter if it's in Bash script or in Google
Apps Script (even if I believe that for Gscript it won't be possible)

*The Google Apps Script code used to extract data from the sheet :*

- Function to convert data Sheet to a string.

```
/**
 * Conversion de la feuille Google Sheets en une chaîne de caractères.
 * Cette chaîne de car. peut servir à la création d'un fichier texte.
 * Le séparateur de ligne est un retour à la ligne (" \n ")
 * Le séparateur de colonne est une tabulation (" \t ")
 * 
 * @param {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} sheet 
 * 
 * @return {String} txt
 */
function _getData( sheet ){
  var numRows = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var data;
  var txt = "";

  try {
      data = sheet.getDataRange().offset( 1, 0, numRows - 1).getDisplayValues(); // récupération des valeurs de la feuille (hormis l'en-tête).
      txt = data.map(function (col) {return col.join('\t');}).join('\n'); // Création d'une chaîne de caractère unique. (Delimiter col : tab ; Delimiter row : backslash)
      
  }catch( err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox('Erreur : ' + err);
  }
  finally{
    return txt;
  }
}
```

- Creation of the text file from a blob

```
/**
 * 
 * Création d'un fichier au format DAT.
 * Le fichier sera situé dans le répertoire : 
 * 
 * 
 * @param {String} extractName
 * @param {String} data
 * 
 * @return {DriveApp.File} file
*/

function createDatFile( extractName, data ){
  var blob;
  var directory;
  var fileName = extractName + ".DAT";
  var file;
  
  try{
    directory = DriveApp.getFolderById(''); // Répertoire Drive Partagé où l'extraction sera effectuée.
    blob = Utilities.newBlob( '' , MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT).setDataFromString( data ); // Création d'un Blob de données à partir d'une chaîne de caractères.
    
    // TODO Supprimer le fichier s'il existe déjà.

    file = DriveApp.createFile( fileName, blob.getDataAsString() ).moveTo( directory ); // Création d'un fichier au format ".DAT" dans un répertoire.

    return file;

  }catch(err){
    Logger.log("Erreur : " + err);
    Browser.msgBox("Erreur : " + err)
  }
}
```

- Main

```
function exportToTextFile() {
  var activeSheet;
  var extractName = "SRC_DATA";
  var data;
  
  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  
  data = _getData( activeSheet ); 

  createDatFile( extractName, data);

  return 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create a text file with the character code of `windows-1252`.

When your script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
blob = Utilities.newBlob( '' , MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT).setDataFromString( data );

// TODO Supprimer le fichier s'il existe déjà.

file = DriveApp.createFile( fileName, blob.getDataAsString() ).moveTo( directory );
```

#### To:

```
blob = Utilities.newBlob("", MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT, fileName).setDataFromString(data, "windows-1252"); // or "CP1252"
file = DriveApp.createFile(blob).moveTo(directory);
```

#### References:

- [setDataFromString(string, charset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setDataFromString(String,String))
- [createFile(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFile(BlobSource))

Comment: Hi @Tanaike,

thank you a lot for your answer, that solved my issue !

Now, I've got an ANSI encoded file on the Google Drive.

Comment: Also, Is it possible to force a CRLF line ending from Google Apps Script ?

Comment: @BigBenne Thank you for replying. About `Hi @Tanaike, thank you a lot for your answer, that solved my issue ! Now, I've got an ANSI encoded file on the Google Drive.`, I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `Also, Is it possible to force a CRLF line ending from Google Apps Script ?`, please modify `txt = data.map(function (col) {return col.join('\t');}).join('\n');` to `txt = data.map(function (col) {return col.join('\t');}).join('\r\n');` and test it again.

Comment: @BigBenne From `Hi @Tanaike, thank you a lot for your answer, that solved my issue ! Now, I've got an ANSI encoded file on the Google Drive.`, when your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Concerning the ' carriage return ',
 
It's perfect, I was looking for this solution through a powershell script but with GScript, it will be all the more simple. 

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: @BigBenne Thank you for replying. From `Concerning the ' carriage return ', It's perfect, I was looking for this solution through a powershell script but with GScript, it will be all the more simple. Thanks a lot for your help !`, I understood that your 1st and 2nd questions were resolved. In this case, please push the accept button. I think that your question and solution will be useful for other people who have the same issue. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer